# Transperent PNG above DIV gives weird results

Tags: html, css

I have weird problem where placing transparent `png` above `div` makes `png` take websites background color and apply it to entire transparent area instead displaying things that are below the image.

Colors of `div` and image are identical.

How I expected it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovIMQ.png

How it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q76H1.png

I'm not really sure maybe it's not even possible enlighten me.

Markup looks like this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menubarwrap">
    <div id="menubar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
    <img class="menu-logo" src="/img/etc..">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper #menubarwrap #menubar {
  margin: 110px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #122137;
}
#wrapper #logo .menu-logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  top: -75px;
  right: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: please put your code here

Comment: As an experiment, does adding background: none to your last block of CSS-code make any difference?

Comment: ...yes It does! make answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the background and it might work. Could you try this CSS:

```css
#wrapper #logo .menu-logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  top: -75px;
  right: calc(50% - 100px);
  background: none;
}
```